# How to use HTTP Client API in Delphi

Tags: http, delphi, delphi-xe8

How to use NetHTTPClient instead of IdHTTP?

My NetHTTPClient code:

```
var
 LHTTPClient: THTTPClient;
 P : TStrings;
 begin
   LHTTPClient := THTTPClient.Create;
   P := TStringList.Create;
   try
     Params.Add('test=' + Path);
     Memo1.Lines.Text := NetHTTPClient1.Post('www.server.com',   P).ContentAsString();
   finally
     LHTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

My IdHTTP code:

```
procedure TForm1.Start;
var
 lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
 P: TStringList;   
begin
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  P := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.Add('test=' + Path);
  try
    Reply.Text := lHTTP.Post('www.server.com', P);

    if AnsiContainsStr(Reply.Text, 'good') then
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Path);
      end;     
  finally
  end;

end;
end.
```

Comment: It would be better if you show the code you have already attempted and explain why you cant fit it in your code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Added what i have tried..

Comment: @RemyLebeau i used your answer, but i should receive a json not html page

Comment: that has nothing to do with the code shown. That is a matter of which URL you request and what parameters you send to it, if any.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neither one of your examples is technically correct.  Your URLs are incomplete, and you are mismanaging your variable names.

Try this instead:

Indy:

```
procedure TForm1.Start;
var
  LHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TStringList;
begin
  LHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    Params := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Params.Add('test=' + Path);
      Memo1.Lines.Text := LHTTP.Post('http://www.server.com', Params);
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LHTTP.Free;
  end;
end.
```

NetHTTP:

```
procedure TForm1.Start;
var
  LHTTP: TNetHTTPClient;
  Params: TStringList;
begin
  LHTTP := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    Params := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Params.Add('test=' + Path);
      Memo1.Lines.Text := LHTTP.Post('http://www.server.com', Params).ContentAsString;
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: how to get the cookie value, there is no `CookieCollection` in `LHTTP.CookieManager` ?

Comment: Embarcadero's [`TNetHTTPClient`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient) component has a [CookieManager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient.CookieManager) property, and its [`TCookieManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClient.TCookieManager) component has a [`Cookies`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClient.TCookieManager.Cookies) property.

Comment: `Cookie := LHTTP.CookieManager.Cookies[' test', 'www.server.com'];` guid me here..

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked to? Have you looked at the class/property declarations? The lookup syntax you are looking for does not exist in `TNetHTTPClient`. Embarcadero's `Cookies` property returns an ordinary dynamic array of `TCookie` objects.  You need to loop through the array manually searching the cookies one by one as needed, eg: `var cookie: TCookie; for cookie in LHTTP.CookieManager.Cookies do begin if (cookie.Domain = 'www.server.com') and (cookie.Name = 'test') then begin ... end; end;`

Comment: alright, how to set the Referer value in `NetHTTPClient`

Comment: @cyberdude look at the [`CustomHeaders`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient.CustomHeaders) property, eg: `LHTTP.CustomHeaders['Referer'] := ...;` if you have any further questions, please post a new question for them.

Comment: alright, my question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647655/how-to-login-to-website-using-http-client-in-delphi-xe]